# PHP preg_replace: to save all the transformed parts into an array

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a large text containing many dates formatted like this:

```
 10 april 2012, monday
```

I need to transform all of them into this format:

```
 \r\nmonday, 10 april 2012
```

So, I wrote a regex and it works perfectly OK.

```
 $matches1= preg_replace(
 '#(\d{,2} [a-z]+) \d{4}, (sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)#u', 
 "\r\n$2$3$4$5$6$7$8, $1", 
 $txt);
```

The problem is that I also need to save all the transformed parts of the text matching the replacement pattern - "\r\n$2$3$4$5$6$7$8, $1" (like \r\nmonday, 10 april 2012) - into an array. So that I have something like this:

```
 Array('\r\nmonday, 10 april 2012', '\r\ntuesday, 11 april 2012', '\r\nfriday, 14 april 2012' etc.)
```

Is that possible?

Replacement pattern ("\r\n$2$3$4$5$6$7$8, $1") comes from a html form and may vary.

### Update

I've tried to write a callback function but I couldn't get the result I needed.
So I've come up with the following:

```
 $text = ...;//some text
 $search = ...;//search pattern
 $replacement = ...;//replacement pattern

 preg_match_all('#' . $search. '#u', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

 foreach ($matches as $match) 
 {
     $replacements[] = preg_replace('#' . $search. '#u', $replacement, $match[0]);
 }

 $newtext = preg_replace('#' . $search. '#u', $replacement, $text);
```

So $newtext contains the transformed text and $replacenemts contains all the replacements.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It can be done using string functions which is easier.

Comment: Yes, I have to use regex. That's just an example, the real regexes may be much more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead (or exemplary in the following code-example additionally) and keep track of all replacements:

```
$search =  '#(\d{,2} [a-z]+) \d{4}, (sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)#u';
$replace = "\r\n$2$3$4$5$6$7$8, $1";
$captured = array();

preg_replace_callback($search, function($matches) use (&$captured)  {
    $captured[] = $matches;    
}, $txt);

$matches1= preg_replace($search, $replace, $txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace_callback and a custom function which stores the matches into an array and returns the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

You could have also split the string at the comma and space in the middle using `$txtArr = explode(', ', $txt, 1);` and then concatenated them back together at the same time as pushing them into an array using `array_push($matches, $txtArr[1].', '.$txtArr[0]);`[1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp). Don't forget define your array you will be adding the dates to (e.g. `$matches = array();`).

If they are in a large string of text, you could locate them using a RegEx function and make use of this to put the "cleaned up" matches into an array.